# add to dictionary values from list of lists in java

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, collections

I have list of lists which called `elephantList` and this is the data on it :

```
elephantList : [[Term1, 3, d3, d5, d43 ], [Term2, 4, d1, d15, d46 ], [Term3, 3, d3, d5, d43], [Term1, 3, d4, d6, d7], [Term2, 4, d2, d3, d4], [Term3, 3, d5, d6, d77]]
```

what I need is to convert this list into ordered dictionary and  I need d's to become also asc ordered and not duplicated.
and become something like this. :

> {Term1=[d3,d4,df,d6,d7,d43], Term2=[d1, d2,d3,d15,d46] ... etc }

So I did this :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < elephantList.size() ; i ++){
    dictionary.put(elephantList.get(i).get(0),elephantList.get(i).subList(2,elephantList.get(i).size()));
}
```

but I just return this :

```
{Term2=[d2, d3, d4], Term1=[d4, d6, d7], Term3=[d5, d6, d77]}
```

**which is not ordered and just last block of each term not all d's**

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an ordered map, a `SortedMap` should be used -- then it will be sorted by keys `Term1, Term2, Term3`

Similarly, to sort the values without duplicates, an *ordered set* should be used to store the values and in this case it should use custom comparator to sort d's as integers: `d1, d2, d3, d15`.

Occasional whitespaces in the d's should be trimmed off using `String::trim`.

```java
SortedMap<String, SortedSet<String>> dictionary = new TreeMap<>();
for (List<String> current : elephantList) {
    dictionary.computeIfAbsent(current.get(0), k -> new TreeSet<>(
        Comparator.comparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1).trim()))
    ))
    .addAll(current.subList(2, current.size()));
}
```

Similar result can be achieved using Stream API: `Collectors.groupingBy` + `Collectors.flatMapping` (Java 9+) + `Collectors.toCollection`:

```java
SortedMap<String, SortedSet<String>> dictionary2 = data
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        lst -> lst.get(0),
        TreeMap::new,
        Collectors.flatMapping(lst -> lst.subList(2, lst.size())
            .stream(),
            Collectors.toCollection(
                () -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(
                    s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1).trim())
                ))
            )
        )
    ));
```

Comment: it's return an error 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "43 "'

Comment: Please check the update, `String::trim` should be used then

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Map<String, List<String>> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
    for (List<String> current : elephantList) {
        List<String> toUpdate = dictionary.computeIfAbsent(current.get(0), ignore -> new ArrayList<>());
        toUpdate.addAll(current.subList(2, current.size()));
    }
```

Comment: Yes It's working, but there's a small problem, I need d's to become also asc ordered but here the output is not

Comment: ordered and not duplicated *